# Extracting Data Using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I display the records received from this query in ASC?

```
SELECT accounts.Nickname, chat.AccountID, chat.Message, chat.DateTime, accounts.Color
FROM (chat INNER JOIN accounts ON chat.AccountID = accounts.AccountID)
ORDER BY chat.MessageID DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: In ascending (ASC) order by what column? Do you want it ascending by Message ID? Do you want last 100 (`DESC LIMIT 100`) and then ascending or what exactly?

Answer (score 4):

Put your original query in a *derived table* (the subquery), and order its result in ASC order.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT accounts.Nickname, chat.AccountID, chat.Message, chat.DateTime, accounts.Color, chat.MessageID 
    FROM (chat INNER JOIN accounts ON chat.AccountID = accounts.AccountID)
    ORDER BY chat.MessageID DESC
    LIMIT 100
) dt
ORDER BY MessageID ASC
```

Comment: "MySQL returned the message:
# 1054 - Unknown 'MessageID' column in order clause"

same situation with chat.MessageID

Comment: Oops, you have to add that column to the SELECT list. Hang on.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what you are talking about, could you do this for me?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Just try the updated query.